# Firebase cannot get the last insert value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a small firebase database with a list. How can I get the last inserted value of the list?
The elements of the list have as key a date string, example:

```
 2016_05_29 --> data
 2016_05_30 --> data
 2016_05_31
 2016_06_01
 2016_06_02
 2016_06_03
 2016_06_10
 2016_06_11
 2016_06_12
 2016_06_13
 2016_06_14
 2016_06_15
 2016_06_16
 2016_06_17
 2016_06_18
 2016_06_19 //returned value
 2016_06_20
 2016_06_21
 2016_06_22
 2016_06_23 //expected value
```

I am try to get the last value of this list, so 2016_06_23 but for some reason it returns this 2016_06_19 whatever key/order system I use:

```
Query dateMaxRef = ref.orderByKey().limitToLast(1); //this returns always 2016_06_19 instead of 2016_06_23 
dateMaxRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
```

....

Any idea?

Comment: That sounds unlike my experience with Firebase. Can you set up a test database (that we can access) and reproduce the entire problem in a jsfiddle or jsbin?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen no I am wrong, there are not 100 values just 70 records, but the limitToLast won't retrive the real last record. I do not understand what is the order...

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Could you figure out how to solve this?

Comment: @Tushar I have did not anything, for some reason, it was fixed itself. Do not know why, probably because the number of the records increased

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue and for me the reason was because the query was not using the latest data from firebase and instead relying on internal cache. Using `.keepSynced(true)` on the query fixed it for me. Below is the sample code -

```
Query causeListPath = mFirebase.child(PATH_CAUSE_LIST).child(SELECTED_CITY)
        .child(SELECTED_COURT_CODE).limitToLast(1);

// If user wants un-cached data, force sync
if (!useCache) causeListPath.keepSynced(true);

causeListPath.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
...
});
```